# Launchpad: Build package on utopic, but release for older versions

Tags: java, ppa, launchpad, debuild

Let's say I want to build an application, that has certain `Build-Depends`, that can only be satisfied on utopic. To be more specific: openjdk-8-jdk*.

The resulting binary will no longer have this dependency and will run flawlessly on lucid (or even older).

Question: Is it somehow possible to mark the source package, so it gets built on utopic for lucid?

---

<sub>* Using Oracle's Java 8 from ppa:webupd8team/java is not an option, as it loads binaries from Oracle, which isn't allowed during build-time.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You can theoretically build on utopic, and then manually sync only the binary packages to the older releases, but you cannot configure Launchpad to do so automatically.

You could also just backport the newer dependencies to the older versions of Ubuntu (trusty and precise) so that you can build the source on all of them, which would be a better solution, as it will catch other possible failures in the future more reliably.

Comment: "sync only the binary packages to the older releases" But that isn't possible on launchpad, is it? Each release needs a source package afaik

Comment: It is possible, yes. You use the _Copy packages_ link, and only copy the binary packages, to the same PPA, but to the older releases.

Comment: Ok, not ideal, but at least a possibility

Comment: It isn't possible to copy *just* binaries in Launchpad; the option you mention copies the source as well as the binaries, it just doesn't rebuild the source package.